# Download File Which has the latest Time Stamp From Website

Tags: bash, curl, download

#### Website is like this

[image]

Can't add the actual site as it's from work.

These files don't have version numbers,
but have different names. No latest file link either, it's a very minimal website.

You can only tell which is the latest by its timestamp.

##### Ideas

- `curl` the webpage, add the files to array, then download the last one in the index with `curl`
- `curl` the webpage, sort each file by its upload date then subtract the upload date from the current date then have `curl` download the file which has the smallest time difference? I'd use `date` to convert to seconds.

Open to a bash solution.

**any better ideas?**

Comment: Difficult to give any solution: all websites have different implementations. The better one have a `latest` file that is linked or redirect to the latest file you want.

Comment: this is just a plain minimal website like those websites with linux files, based on the timestamps can I not just target that file? I clearly described the type of website this is and that it doesn't have such features

Comment: Not clear what kind of website you mean.  in general, no such thing is possible, because http in general doesn't at all allow for listing if all files.

Comment: [Do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Use plain text instead.

Comment: it's not an error. It shows the type of site, so you, @sinabala and others know what I mean. Doesn't fall under input/code/data/errors, but thanks.

Comment: The given image could be the result of any number of HTML codes. The actual HTML should be shown here as text if it is to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

One generic approach, using a hacky way: [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/) that can be parsed:

```
lftp -e "find -l; quit" https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/
```

An example of parsing with basic tools:

```
lftp -e "find -l; quit" https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/ |
    awk '{print $3"-"$4, $5}' |
    sort |
    tail -n1 |
    cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Yields the latest file from remote web site.

Comment: thank you this is the type of idea  I was looking for, it's a better approach than what I had in mind (I'd get the page do a bunch of parsing etc) I added a picture of what the site looks like can't add the actual site as it's my in my work

Comment: What is the output of my `lftp` command?

Comment: I'll try after work